# Partial fold of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

How to apply [fold](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) functions only finite number of times, instead of folding the entire list? For example, this incomplete fold would sum up only first 3 numbers, leaving the rest untouched:

```
foldlN 3 (+) [1..5] -- [6,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems simple just to fold on a part of list, then cons it to the rest of the list:

```
foldlN :: Int -> (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
foldlN n f xs = (foldl1 f $ take n xs) : drop n xs
```

Result in REPL:

```
*Main> foldlN 3 (+) [1..5]
[6,4,5]
```

If you worry that taking and then dropping from the same list is a double job, you can rewrite with [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3asplitAt):

```
foldlN n f xs = (foldl1 f $ fst t) : snd t
  where t = splitAt n xs
```

Note the type of the function, you can't base your fold on `foldl`, because you can't have a list `[[1,2,3],4,5,6]` in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

First, *folding* a list with `(+)` doesn't produce a list, it produces a single answer. Perhaps you want `scanl` or `scanr`?

```
scanl (+) 0 [1..5] -- [0, 0+1, 0+1+2, 0+1+2+3, ...]
```

So if you wanted to add only the first 3 numbers, that would be the 4th element of this list;

```
(scanl (+) 0 [1..5]) !! 3
```

Alternatively, you could just cut the list down to 3 elements:

```
foldl (+) 0 (take 3 [1..5])
```